# как сделать jquery masked input на несколько телефонов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery masked input плагин.
Есть несколько полей с телефонами с таким классом, но работает почему-то на самом первом

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("input.phoneInput").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Comment: необходим пример

Comment: Значит только один инпут соответствует селектору "input.phoneInput"